# my local storage fails to save, no idea why, first time using it

Tags: javascript, html

i got this function that's executed upon other things upon page load,
it does save the items correctly till the page is refreshed,
i want to use that array to calculate maximum score from it on future games,
some explanation would help
first time using JSON aswell

the code:

```
localStorage.setItem("scroes", JSON.stringify(gBestScores));
    var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("scroes");
    gscores = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
```

gBestScores is an empty array that gets pushed a value each time the game ends or is restarted,
not saved in localstorage, checked and works fine,
gScores is an undefined variable at the top of the page, tried setting it to an empty array didnt make much difference

Comment: typo warning: should *scroes* be *scores*?

Comment: You have to save `gBestScores` in local storage each time it is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as it is doesn't load the scores up or save the scores properly.

It should be:

When the page / game load up, or before you need to display them or have them for insertion:

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("scores");
gscores = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
```

When the game ends:

```
// if game score is higher than the best scores, insert it into gBestScores
localStorage.setItem("scores", JSON.stringify(gBestScores));
```

Also, wouldn't you use the same array for the highest scores? Right now you are using two: `gscores` and `gBestScores`.